# problem in encoding .csv file content conversion to .json file

Tags: python, json

I use this piece of code to convert a `.csv` file content to a `.json` file:

```
import csv
import json

with open('export.csv', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    rows = list(reader)

with open('test.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(rows, f)
```

The conversion is successful, but Arabic characters in `.csv` file convert to something like this in `.json` file:

```
"\u06a9\u0627"
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `json.dump` docstring:

> If `ensure_ascii` is false, then the strings written to `fp` can
> contain non-ASCII characters if they appear in strings contained in
> `obj`. Otherwise, all such characters are escaped in JSON strings.

Solution:

```
json.dump(rows, f, ensure_ascii=False)
```